# what if glide gives an error in andorid

Tags: android, firebase

I am stuck thinking that I am developing an which provide a way to advertise their products, but I am confused what if glide gives an error in certain position of recyclerview, what should I do and how to manage that? Should I remove recyclerview item at that position or do something else because it degrades my app quality? One more thing, why the popular apps ex: facebook, instagram does not get such errors, because I never found any error image in their recyclerview how they do it?

my backend is firebase;

Comment: You can set default placeholder to view, or can implement callback for success and failure, and set default image to view in failure.

Answer (score 0):

If Glide cannot load image at specific place. You can use a placeholder or error to managed it.

See docs:
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html

My Facebook app sometime cannot load image because my internet connection too slow, and it become blank.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and other application has button to retry, when error comes. you can do as below in `bindViewHolder` method for `RecyclerView` and `getView` method for `ListView`:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getImageUrl())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                    if (holder.mimageView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        holder.mimageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (holder.btnRetry.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.btnRetry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mimageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                    if (holder.mimageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.mimageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (holder.btnRetry.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        holder.btnRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Now on `btnRetry` click you can again fetch image using glide as above.

Answer (score 0):

If Glide encounters an error while loading an image, it can throw an exception. In this case, you can catch the exception and handle it appropriately.

One common approach is to display a placeholder image or a default image in place of the failed image. You can do this by setting a placeholder or fallback image in the Glide request. For example:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
     .error(R.drawable.error_image)
     .into(imageView);
```

In the above code, R.drawable.placeholder_image is the image that will be displayed while the actual image is being loaded, and R.drawable.error_image is the image that will be displayed if the image fails to load.

If you are using Glide with RecyclerView, you can use the same approach to handle errors. When an image fails to load, you can display a placeholder or fallback image in the ImageView of the affected RecyclerView item.

As for why popular apps like Facebook and Instagram do not show error images in their RecyclerViews, it's likely because they have a robust error handling mechanism in place. They may be catching and handling exceptions, or they may be using other techniques to ensure that images are always loaded successfully. It's also possible that they have a team of experienced developers who have optimized their code for performance and reliability.